# What is the margin of a Dialog?

Tags: android, android-alertdialog

Dialogs in Android don't completely fill the screen by default. How is this calculated? Is it set to `match_parent` with a `layout_margin`? What is the `layout_margin` value?

I can't seem to find an easy answer to this.

Comment: You would have to find the relevant attribute in the relevant theme. Why do you need to know?